# How to check if all authenticated users has read permissions on a site collection?

Tags: permissions

I would like to check if "all authenticated users" has read permissions on a site collection. If it is not existed I would like to add the permissions. How to do that?

I tried this but it is not working:

```
SPUser allusers = site.OpenWeb().EnsureUser("NT AUTHORITY\\authenticated users");

            if (site.OpenWeb().DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
            {
                if (!site.OpenWeb().DoesUserHavePermissions(allusers.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open))
                {
                    //do something
                    site.OpenWeb().SiteUsers.Add("NT AUTHORITY\\authenticated users", string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which user you are asking about is that about a current logged in user???

Comment: If you want to give read access to the users then add them to the visitors group of the sharepoint site.